# How to make menu hierarchy flowchart in ReactJS or HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image: Figma design]

Hey, I am working on a side project in which I am want to develop react component which can render details on the top bar with text and two buttons and at the bottom, a hierarchy styled like a menu flowchart. each menu option will expand further when the plus sign is clicked and collapse when the minus sign is clicked.

I am a beginner in reactjs, I don't know how to render such components, can you help me here?

If you have any question please comment below and thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything you have tried at this point?

Comment: Yeah, it is not same, and there are lots of limitations. https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/

Comment: Can you provide some sample object, with which you want to render that hierarchy of flowchart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursive approach where you render children (nested) elements inside the component by using `map` method as long as there is children property and `isOpen` is true.

The data structure is an array of object where each object has `title`, `text` and `children` property which is an array of the same structure. This will work on the data of any level of depth.

```js
const data = [{"title":"item-1","text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.","children":[{"title":"item-1-1","text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.","children":[{"title":"item-1-1-1","text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."},{"title":"item-1-1-2","text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."}]},{"title":"item-1-2","text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."}]},{"title":"Item 2","text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.","children":[{"title":"Item 4","text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."}]}]

const { useState } = React;

const App = ({ items }) => (
  items.map((item, i) => (
    <Item {...item} key={i}/>
  ))
)

const ItemHeader = ({ title, isOpen, setIsOpen }) => (
  <div className="item-header">
    <span>{title}</span>
    <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>{isOpen ? '-' : '+'}</button>
  </div>
)

const ItemBody = ({ text, children, isOpen }) => (
  <div className={`item-body ${isOpen ? 'show' : 'hide'}`}>
    <p>{text}</p>
  </div>
)

const Item = ({ title, text, children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="item">
      <div class="item-content">
        <ItemHeader
          title={title}
          isOpen={isOpen}
          setIsOpen={setIsOpen}/>

        <ItemBody
          isOpen={isOpen}
          text={text}
          children={children}/>
      </div>

      <div class="item-children">
        {children && isOpen && children.map((item, i) => <Item {...item} key={i}/>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App items={data}/>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
)
```

```css
.item {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item-content {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #252525;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-header button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

p {
  margin: 5px 0
}

.item-children {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I have already made similar features, the main problem that I am facing is connecting each component via lines, something like Twitter posts. how can I achieve such features.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer.** *When people asked in the comments "what you have tried so far?", they except to help your on resolving some issue, and not "making it for you". Make sure to try something, before blindly asking.*

You don't need libraries to make it (from your current version of the question). All you need to do, it's implement Composite pattern of the Component. Very simple example:

```
export class FlowItem extends React.Component {

   render() {
      const {header, children} = this.props;

      return (
         <div>
             Ping from {header}
             <div style={{marginLeft: '20px'}}>
                 {children}
             <div/>

         <div/>
      );
   }
}
```

And it's usage **example** below.

```
export class Content extends React.Component {

   render() {

      return (
         <div
            <FlowItem 
              header={"Very Top 1"}>
                  <FlowItem 
                     header={"Parent 1"}>
                  <FlowItem/>
            <FlowItem/>


            <FlowItem 
              header={"Very Top 2"}>
                  <FlowItem 
                     header={"Parent 1"}>
                  <FlowItem/>

                  <FlowItem 
                     header={"Parent 2"}>
                      <FlowItem header={"Child 1"}/>
                      <FlowItem header={"Child 2"}/>
                  <FlowItem/>

                  <FlowItem 
                     header={"Parent 3"}>
                  <FlowItem/>
            <FlowItem/>

         <div/>
      );
   }
}
```

Another simple **example** if you want to use with real objects in the array. I think it's your case from the question:

```
export class Content extends React.Component {

   render() {

      const root = {
       header: "Root 1",
       children: [
       {
        header: "Parent 1",
        children: [
         {
           header: "Child 1",
           children: [
            {
              header: "Inner 1",
              children: null
            }
           ]
         },
         {
           header: "Child 2",
           children: null
         }, 
         {
           header: "Child 3",
           children: null
         }
        ]
       },

       {
        header: "Parent 2",
        children: [
         {
           header: "Child 1",
           children: null
         },
         {
           header: "Child 2",
           children: null
         }
        ]
       },
      ]};

      return (
         <div>
            {this.getItemView(root)}
         <div/>
      );
   }

   getItemView = (node) => {
        return (
           <FlowItem 
             header={node.header}>
             {node.children ?
                node.children.map((obj, idx) => {
                  
                return (this.getItemView(obj));
           
             }) : <div/>}
           <FlowItem/>
        );
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible with PURE CSS and JS, check it and expand it as you need.

> [Mutilevel menu example at w3School](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h)